# Advanced search on age and scheduleRange criteria

Tags: php

I'm working on a website allowing to manage candidacies.
Several features are already realized.

Now, I'm realizing an advanced search on several criteria as zipcode, age, scheduleRange, and more.
I'm stuck for the age and scheduleRange comparison. 
In my database, when a candidacy is created, that's not age which is stored, but birthday in Y-m-d format, and for scheduleRange, that's stored in the form : 09:00-17:00. 
How from these data, I can compare them with the seized data. For example, if I seize as value 07:30 and 15:30, I fetch all schedules between the seized values
And if I seize as value 15 and 40 for age, I fetch all age between the seized values.

```
<?php
    $stmt = $cnx->prepare("SELECT scheduleRange FROM candidacies");
    $stmt->execute();

    $test = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($test as $key => $value)
    {
        $values = explode("-", $value['scheduleRange']);
        echo $values;
    }
```

Here is the result :

> 10:0015:0009:0017:0009:0017:0008:3017:0008:0016:0009:0017:0008:0012:0009:0021:0008:3016:0009:0017:0007:0016:3008:4516:4509:0018:0009:0017:00

I was thinking of using explode() function . It is a good start?

Comment: Are you open to changing how `scheduleRange` is stored?

Comment: I really can't understand what is your question?

Comment: yeah sure ! @Patrick Q

Comment: what are you not understanding? @D.Dimitrov

Comment: I would suggest storing the start and end times in two different columns of the `time` datatype. You should also clarify what defines a matched result for the schedule search. In your example of searching for 07:30 to 15:30, do the matched records need to both start _and_ end between those two times? Is a record with a start time of 08:00 and an end time of 17:00 a match? What about a record that starts at 06:00 and ends at 12:00?

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be a simple solution to clarify my problem ! Hum, all searches will need to be between starting time and end time

Comment: But by leaving of this solution, how can I write my query with BETWEEN operator?? @Patrick Q

Comment: Something along the lines of `startCol between X and Y and endCol between X and Y and startCol < endCol`